# Is it possible to run a script in context of a webpage, before any of the webpage's scripts run, using a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have tried `"run_at": "document_start"`, but there is no DOM when the extension gets control, so I can not insert the `script` into `head`. Also, tried to use `DOMNodeInserted`, but it is not fired for `head`. if I try to insert the `script` on first `DOMNodeInserted` event, it gets executed after the webpage's scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root element always exist. You can just append the `<script>` to the `<html>` element:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = 'console.log("Test");';
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
s.parentNode.removeChild(s); // Just to clean-up.
```

Comment: There is no guarantee about the executing order of dynamic inserted script tag. So this method may fail in some time.